Acumatica Upgrade Broke Custom Action in Mobile App
I have a customization that was written originally for
Acumatica 2021 R2 (Build 21.218.0027) and it runs fine there.
It adds an action button to the opportunities screen (CR304000) (See screenshots below)
The purpose of this button is to have the tech in the field be able to press it to call out to a web based forms system we have developed. So, I have code in the customization to make it visible on the mobile app:
update screen CR304000
  {
    update container "OpportunitySummary"
     {
      add recordAction "ASGExtForms"
       {
         behavior = void
         redirect = True
       }
     }

This works fine in Acumatica 2021 R2, Build  21.218.0027.
However, it will not work in Acumatica 2022 R2, Build 22.223.0007
Everything compiles fine, but the button will not show in the Mobile app.
Weirdly, I have almost identical code for the Appointments screen (FS300200), and the action shows there.
Does anyone have any idea what changed, and how I have to change the mobile app code (I am assuming) to get this to work again?
In case it is helpful, here is the definition in C# for the button,
and the code that enables the button on the back end web service:
public override void Initialize()
 {
     base.Initialize(); 

            Base.actionsFolder.AddMenuAction(asgExtForms);

 }

// The definition of asgExtForms
        public PXAction<CROpportunity> asgExtForms;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "DoorForm", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXButton]
     public virtual void ASGExtForms()
     {
        // do the code here to run the web forms
     }

Here are screenshots it running correctly in the older version of the Mobile App:
Opportunities:

Appointments (Notice it is in the ellipsis menu here. IDK why.)

